# Позиционирование элементов с помощью css

Tags: css

Как с помощью CSS разместить элементы так, как указано на картинке ниже? Мне нужно чтобы круги с датой располагались четко в центре, а слева и справа от них можно было писать текст. Также чтобы это было адаптивно.
Пробовал с помощью флексбоксов, но не хватает команды "justify-self" для этого. Подскажите, как это возможно реализовать?
[image: example]

P.S. когда-то видел такую реализацию на сайтах, но не могу вспомнить где именно. Если кто-то знает сайт с подобной реализацией - буду рад, если поделитесь, там уже разберусь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

h2 {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  background: silver;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  line-height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: inherit;
}

section:nth-child(odd) {
  border-right-color: black;
  padding-right: 3em;
}

section:nth-child(odd) h2 {
  margin-right: -3rem;
  padding-right: 3rem;
}

section:nth-child(odd) span {
  right: -2rem;
}

section:nth-child(even) {
  border-left-color: black;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 3em;
}

section:nth-child(even) h2 {
  margin-left: -3rem;
  padding-left: 3rem;
}

section:nth-child(even) span {
  left: -2rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h2>Первая секция<span>1970</span></h2>
  <p>Как с помощью CSS разместить элементы так, как указано на картинке ниже? Мне нужно чтобы круги с датой располагались четко в центре, а слева и справа от них можно было писать текст. Также чтобы это было адаптивно. Пробовал с помощью флексбоксов, но не хватает команды "justify-self" для этого. Подскажите, как это возможно реализовать?</p>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>Вторая секция<span>1980</span></h2>
  <p>Как с помощью CSS разместить элементы так, как указано на картинке ниже? Мне нужно чтобы круги с датой располагались четко в центре, а слева и справа от них можно было писать текст. Также чтобы это было адаптивно. Пробовал с помощью флексбоксов, но не хватает команды "justify-self" для этого. Подскажите, как это возможно реализовать?</p>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>Третья секция<span>1990</span></h2>
  <p>Как с помощью CSS разместить элементы так, как указано на картинке ниже? Мне нужно чтобы круги с датой располагались четко в центре, а слева и справа от них можно было писать текст. Также чтобы это было адаптивно. Пробовал с помощью флексбоксов, но не хватает команды "justify-self" для этого. Подскажите, как это возможно реализовать?</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Что-то типа того ...

```css
.block_item {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  clear: both;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block_title { position: relative; }

.block_titleYear {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 56px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -28px 0 0 -28px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.block_item:nth-child(2n-1) { float: left; }
.block_item:nth-child(2n) { float: right; }

.block_item:nth-child(2n-1)::after,
.block_item:nth-child(2n)::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.block_item:nth-child(2n-1)::after { left: 100%; }
.block_item:nth-child(2n)::after { left: 0; }

.block_item:nth-child(2n-1) .block_titleYear { left: 100%; }
.block_item:nth-child(2n) .block_titleYear { left: 0; }

.block_item:nth-child(2n-1) .block_title,
.block_item:nth-child(2n-1) .block_content {
  padding-right: 56px;
}

.block_item:nth-child(2n) .block_title,
.block_item:nth-child(2n) .block_content {
  padding-left: 56px;
}

.block_item:nth-child(1) .block_title,
.block_item:nth-child(1) .block_titleYear {
  background-color: green;
}

.block_item:nth-child(2) .block_title,
.block_item:nth-child(2) .block_titleYear {
  background-color: red;
}

.block_item:nth-child(3) .block_title,
.block_item:nth-child(3) .block_titleYear {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block_item">
    <p class="block_title">
      <span class="block_titleYear">1970</span>
      <span class="block_titleText">Заголовок №1</span>
    </p>
    <div class="block_content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block_item">
    <p class="block_title">
      <span class="block_titleYear">1970</span>
      <span class="block_titleText">Заголовок №1</span>
    </p>
    <div class="block_content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block_item">
    <p class="block_title">
      <span class="block_titleYear">1970</span>
      <span class="block_titleText">Заголовок №1</span>
    </p>
    <div class="block_content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```